# Windows 8.1 displaying favicon in pinned site tile instead of image

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, pinned-site

I am trying to display images on the pinned site tile for my website but for some reason it just keeps displaying the favicon.

If I uncomment out the meta tags for the Windows 8.1 pinned site tiles, then the Windows 8 pinned site tile meta tag works but if I don't uncomment it, both do not work.

Here is my code:

```
<#-- Pinning site to Windows start page. -->
<meta name="application-name" content=""/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name=msapplication-starturl content="my_url">

<#-- Windows 8. -->
<meta name=msapplication-TileImage content="/images/ms-pinned-site.png">

<#-- Windows 8.1. -->
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/images/ms-pinned-square.png">
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/images/ms-pinned-wide.png">
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/images/ms-pinned-large.png">
```

The sizes for the images are as follows:

Square: 150x150: image size: 149x157
Wide: 310x150: image size: 507x240
Large: 310x310: image size: 443x426

Any help would greatly be appreciated.